# zebra barcode printing example for CPCL language

Tags: vb.net, zebra-printers

Is the any sources for examples for barcode printing for zebra rw420 mobile printer? which is CPCL language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

qr-code example using the  CPCL printer language:

```
    ! 0 200 200 500 1
    B QR 10 100 M 2 U 10
    MA,QR code ABC123
    ENDQR
    FORM
    PRINT
```